# Strange Folder Called David_Dolinski

Tags: windows

Under C:\Users\\AppData\Local there's a folder called David_Dolinski. I have no idea what it is. There's nothing in it.  Is it malware or something?

And no, my name is not David Dolinski.

Comment: That is a strange address you have pasted, something wrong C:\Users\\AppData\Local

Answer (score 0):

Ever used [SubViewer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubViewer)? If so, it might simply be some leftover folder. Nothing to worry about. There's possibly other software by other persons with this name.

Comment: please include link to software